# proof that this is of class $C^{+\infty}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> consider $f(x,y,z)=x^4+2x\cos y+\sin z$, proof that in a neighborhood of $0$, the equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ sets $z$ as a function of class $C^{\infty}$ of the variables $x,y$. compute $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

i set $f(x,y,z)=0$ then

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y,z)&=x^4+2x\cos y+\sin z\\
f(x,y,z)&=0\\
x^4+2x\cos y+\sin z&=0\\
\sin z&=-x^4-2x\cos y\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sin z&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(-x^4-2x\cos y\right)\\
\cos z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}&=-4x^3-2\cos y\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}&=\frac{-4x^3-2\cos y}{\cos z}\\
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\sin z&=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(-x^4-2x\cos y\right)\\
\cos z\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}&=2x\sin y\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}&=\frac{2x\sin y}{\cos z}
\end{align}$$

but how i can prove that the function $z$ is function of Class $C^{\infty}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $(x,y)\in (-1/3,1/3)\times \mathbb {R},$ we have $-x^4 -2x\cos y \in (-1,1).$ Hence for such an $(x,y)$ there is a unique $z\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ such that $\sin z = -x^4 -2x\cos y.$ That $z$ is of course $\arcsin (-x^4 -2x\cos y).$ So there's your function of $(x,y).$ It's a composition of $C^\infty$ functions, and so belongs to $C^\infty ((-1/3,1/3)\times \mathbb {R}).$ (Note: The interval $(-1/3,1/3)$ was just the first thing I saw that would things work out nicely - nothing special about it.)